# SQLite LINQ and POCO

Tags: vb.net, linq, sqlite, windows-runtime, poco

I'm currently trying to learn SQLite, in a VB.NET WinRT project. 
I've use "SQLite Expert" to generate my database. Now that my database is ready on how to implement some code, but I'm wondering how to create my POCOs object/Object representing my database object.

Do I need to code by hand all objects, to have them available to LINQ to object?
Also, how to manage mapping between SQLite table and Class Object

Comment: Seems like your looking for an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) like NHibernate/Entity Framework - a very broad subject.

Comment: It depends on many factors. Please, provide more details about your requirements.

Comment: As far as I know Entity Framework is not available on Windows 8 Metro App. I'm looking to have a mapper (ORM as your say) for my SQLite database. Is there any ORM out there for SQLite and Metro App?

Comment: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/10/database-first-with-sqlite-in-universal.html

Comment: Thanks ErikEJ that look like promising

Comment: In my research I found the tool named LinqConnect by Devart.com. It look like a very complet tools! http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/